# Migrate all the users set in roles strategy of a jenkins server to another jenkins server.

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I migrated all the Jenkins related file from one server to another. Everything is working fine. The only problem is I am not able to see all the users and project role which were set in previous Jenkins server. I am using Role-based Authorization strategy. Any way of getting all the previous users in the new Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

I had same task to migrate jenkins from one server to another and the solution I used was `rsync` which did the job.

If you have *nix servers, I would suggest you to go via `rsync` also

Comment: jobs and everything is migrated but project roles and users are not migrated.

Comment: when I did migration via ```rsync``` everything was migrated